# Orange Pi 2G IoT (Debian) останавливается при загрузке

Tags: linux, debian, orange-pi

После непродолжительной работы с различным софтом, debian перестал загружаться, останавливаясь на этих строках:

```
[  OK  ] Started LSB: Set console font and keymap.
[    7.307128] rda_msys: rda-codec : timeout as sending a message
[    7.307739] >>>> [aud_Setup], ret [1] 
[    7.347167] rda_msys: rda-apsys : timeout as sending a message
[    7.347717] Failed as setting aux_clk
[  OK  ] Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill0.
[  OK  ] Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill2.
```

Первым делом заподозрил SD карту, так как при неправильном отключении питания, файловая система может сломаться, однако, после запуска fsck на оба раздела на SD карте, получил в ответ, что всё с ФС хорошо.

Лог: http://pastebin.ru/GonKx2Bs

Comment: Ядро у вас грузится (кое-как, выкиньте всё то, что вы сами туда понавтыкали), дальше у вас systemd ждёт модуля который ломает всё.  Чего вы хотите собственно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас не загружается модуль alsa. В репозиториях пакет со старой версией. Новая версия, собранная вручную, решает проблему при запуске.

Актуальную версия исходного кода можно получить с [AlsaProject](https://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Main_Page)

Comment: Можно подробнее что именно необходимо брать и как собирать, а так же как обновить этот модуль если система не загружается